# uninstall mysql completely from linux mint

Tags: mysql, linux

I have mysql 5.5 installed in my system and i want to install new version ie. mysql 5.7 , so i am struggling to uninstall the older version. when i will try to install 5.7 ,it is installing 5.5. so i need help ...
here is the command i executed:-

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'mysql-client' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client-core-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-common' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 254 not upgraded.
```

** I don't understand why 254 was not upgraded

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql

sudo apt-get autoremove
  

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 254 not upgraded.
```

```
sudo apt-get autoclean

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

$ mysql --version(i jsust tyied to check the version)

The program 'mysql' can be found in the following packages:
 * mysql-client-core-5.5
 * mariadb-client-core-5.5
 * mysql-client-core-5.6
 * percona-xtradb-cluster-client-5.5
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server

Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libmysqlclient18 libterm-readkey-perl
  mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server-5.5
  mysql-server-core-5.5
Suggested packages:
  libmldbm-perl libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl libsql-statement-perl tinyca
  mailx
Recommended packages:
  libhtml-template-perl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libmysqlclient18 libterm-readkey-perl
  mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server
  mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 254 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/9,257 kB of archives.
After this operation, 96.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
******
```

its installing the previous version instead of new version.
so please help me

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate on the related site http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux). Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me in Linux mint 20

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Answer (score 1):

`apt` automatically installs the latest version available in the added repositories.

to see all the available versions in your enabled repositories, run

```
apt-cache policy mysql-server
```

if the version you want to install is not listed in the output, then you might need to add extra repositories.

Coming to      `254 not upgraded` part, it just means that updates for 254 packages are available in the repositories.
You can install those updates using

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this command to remove MySQL completely from your current Linux system including your databases, settings and everything else.

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql
```

Hopefully I didn't mistyped :p
Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: @Gopalkrishnasudhanshu what does it tell you?

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql

Comment: actually i uninstalled mysql , while checking version its showing like-- mysql --version
The program 'mysql' can be found in the following packages:
 * mysql-client-core-5.5
 * mariadb-client-core-5.5
 * mysql-client-core-5.6
 * percona-xtradb-cluster-client-5.5

Comment: @Gopalkrishnasudhanshu oh try the same command with mysql* at the end -> * as placeholder

Comment: @Gopalkrishnasudhanshu i am facing the same problem i have to uninstall mysql completly did you find solution ?

Comment: yeah, uninstall completely and it was showing some file is skipped. after that i installed the older version 5.5 using synaptic package manager and  then upgrade it to 5.6 then again upgrade to 5.7

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling it from software manager and restart the system, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following command :

```
# rpm -qa | grep mysql
```

It will list all installed mysql packages on your system. Eg: mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64

now execute the command:

```
# yum remove <name displayed in above step-1>

Eg: yum remove mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
```